# Images showing in weird colors

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am creating a new 2d game engine in lwjgl 3 using OpenGL to try out lwjgl 3 as this is the first project I'm using lwjgl 3 in all my other projects have had lwjgl 2. But when I render an image using that new engine all the colors change and some don't even show up.

> Code for loading textures

```
    public Texture(String filename){
    IntBuffer width = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    IntBuffer height = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    IntBuffer comp = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);

    ByteBuffer data = stbi_load(filename, width, height, comp, 4);

    id = glGenTextures();
    this.width = width.get();
    this.height = height.get();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, this.width, this.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_BYTE, data);
    stbi_image_free(data);

}
```

> Texture i tried to render (with a resolution of 16x16)
>   [image: input]
>
> Render
>   [image: result]

If you know how i could this prevent from happening please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, this.width, this.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_BYTE, data);
>                                                                              ^^^^^^^
> ```

`GL_BYTE` is a *signed* 8 Bit integer type, so all your values > 127 will end up being interpreted as negative values (assuming your platform uses standard two's complement representation at least) and be clamped to 0.

Just use `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.

Comment: To add to this answer, when dealing with image data, you can almost always assume it's using unsigned bytes.